# Book review of "A Practitioner's Guide to Resampling for Data Analysis, Data Mining and Modeling"

Tags: references, resampling

I am looking at the text, *A Practitioner's Guide to Resampling for Data Analysis, Data Mining, and Modeling*, by Phillip Good ([Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439855501)).

- I would like to see if anyone has read this book (or seen a review) and can offer objective advice on it (rating and level of material).

(I have a suspicion this question - being subjective - should be placed in a community location. Problem is, not sure how to do that. So, I will beg forgiveness in advance and look to a moderator to help direct me.)

Comment: I have not consulted with the other mods, but IMHO it's possible for reviews to be objective by describing *how* and *why* a book might be suitable for certain purposes or audiences, so we might be able to dance around some of the difficulties by soliciting reviews of this nature.  Also, books last long enough that we can avoid the temporal localization problem that would attach to reviews of (say) Web pages or magazine articles.  But any reply that merely says "I liked it" or "this book is great for undergraduates" will be quickly deleted.

Comment: I agree that a well-argumented review might qualify as a ["valid, helpful and knowledgeable answer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55888/when-to-mark-the-community-wiki-checkbox-on-a-new-question). (Incidentally, we both pointed to some of Good's textbooks on a [related question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5845/good-text-for-resampling).)