# pvalue to determine if an observed value is in the upper or lower tail of boostrapped data

Tags: mathematical-statistics, p-value, bootstrap

I have a question about finding a pvalue on bootstrapped data, which is very similar to [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41009/questions-on-bootstrap-methods-on-calculating-p-value).

I have a numeric vector `S` of bootstrapped simulated data, for instance `N` values between 0 and 1, and one observed numeric data `X`, and I want to compute a pvalue which indicates if the observed value is more likely in the upper or lower tail (so, if I understand well, if the value `X` is significantly lower or higher than the null distribution).

I found the simple formula for the pvalue which computes the chances for x to be in the upper tail :

`p = sum(S > X)/N` and it's corrected one : `p = (sum(S >X)+1)/(N+1)`. So if `p > 0.05`, `X` is most likely not in the upper tail. According to an article I found ([here, on page 2](http://qed.econ.queensu.ca/working_papers/papers/qed_wp_1127.pdf)), this pvalue can be seen as the proportion of boostrapped values which are more extreme than the observed value.

My questions (probably a bit silly) are :

- is the equivalent formula for the lower tail `p = sum(S<X)/N` ? (**edit** : according to the article I'm reading, yes)
- is there a formula for a two-sided pvalue ? because if I add the result of the two previous formula, I'll get `1` of course.
- Like mentionned in the question linked above, is it correct to use the Z-table (assuming my boostrapped data are normally distributed) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General: please read the answer of @whuber in the question that you are linking.

Ad 1: yes

Ad 2: I think it is more complicated.

If S follows a distribution which is symmetric around 0, then you can simply use `(abs(S) > abs(X))/N`

However, if I did not know anything about the distribution of S, then I would take the pairs quantiles of the experimental S distribution and ask whether X is within them. For example, if

```
X < quantile(S, 0.005) | X > quantile(S, 0.995)
```

then I would say that `p < 0.01` in a two-tailed comparison.

Ad 3. I think the answer is no, since you are calculating your z scores based on mean which is calculated from the samples which undergo the test.

Comment: Thanks ! I had trouble to understand @whuber's answer. Now it's clear.